# Spring Cloud Zuul: How to handle authorizations within Service?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Spring Cloud Zuul is most commonly used with JWT to authorize/decide if a user has access or not to a particular service. But this seems to be quite high level.

What I mean is, if there are services to which users can have full or part access, how to go about it. As an example, if there is PhotoAlubum service - which allows

1. certain users to view photos/albums,
2. certain users to edit tags/albums etc,
3. certain users to create new alubums and
4. certain users to add photos

Now from my understanding, Zuul, will either allow or deny a users access to a service. If the user has no access to the service then denying is fine. But what about above situation, if the user has access to the service but has limited authorisation, the user can still perform any of the above actions.    **How to handle this situation using ZUUL or Spring Security**.

Edit - as a related Q - Does zuul allow url and method based access apart from service based access.

Comment: Doing that on `Zuul` level will be way too complex and will couple way too much the downstream service to the API Gateway. However, if you still want to do it, you can create your own filters and add the required validations on every request.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero, I have edited Q to include Spring Secruity based solution used JWT. Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When the API Gateway receives the request, you can intercept it by adding a filter use the JWT to determine whether or not the consumer has permissions to perform the operation, and then allow or deny it to go to the downstream service.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero, that is exactly the problem, in my example there are four roles - so zuul will have to allow a request (JWT token) with any of the four roles to allow access to the service. But now the problem starts, if the user with viewalbum or edittags is allowed to access the photosalbums service, he can still add/delete photos/albums

Comment: @MarcosBarbero, does zuul allow url and method based access apart from service based access.  Edited my Q to reflect this

Comment: Spring Security can be handy for you, maybe this link gives you some ideas https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/authorization.html#el-access-web